# Getting Connection Refused with WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I made an service using WCF and can't connect to it, I keep getting the following error:

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:5555/ControlChannel. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0139182. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5555.

This is the code:

Contract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IControlChannelCallback))]
public interface IControlChannel
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Join();
}
```

CallBackContract:

```
public interface IControlChannelCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ShowMessage(string message);
}
```

Service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public sealed class ControlChannel : IControlChannel
{
    public static readonly IList<IControlChannelCallback> Callbacks = new List<IControlChannelCallback>(); 

    public void Join()
    {
        var client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IControlChannelCallback>();

        if (!Callbacks.Contains(client))
            Callbacks.Add(client);

        client.ShowMessage("This message came from the server");
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public MainForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ControlChannel)))
     {
          host.Open();
     }
 }
```

Client:

```
public MainForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     var callback = new ControlChannelCallbackClient();

     using (var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IControlChannel>(callback, "Client"))
     {
          var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

          proxy.Join();
     }
 }
```

App.config client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
        <endpoint name="Client"
                  contract="Service.Contracts.Interfaces.IControlChannel"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  address="net.tcp://localhost:5555/ControlChannel" />
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

App.config server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="Service.Contracts.Objects.ControlChannel">
          <endpoint contract="Service.Contracts.Interfaces.IControlChannel"
                    binding="netTcpBinding"
                    address="net.tcp://localhost:5555/ControlChannel" >
          </endpoint>
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a code problem or should I start looking for problems elsewhere?

Comment: I doubt this is the root cause, but why is your service contract's implementing class marked `sealed`?

Comment: Where's the rest of your host? Are you sure the application is still running at the time the client connects? Try `netstat -n -a | findstr "5555"` from a command prompt to see if your host is still there.

Comment: Did you turn on logging to see if it will provide some more info? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Comment: Apparently there is nothing listening on 5555. How come? The server does not throw any kind of exception at all.

Comment: You have your service host in a using block, and you have nothing after you open it, so after the constructor exits, the service host is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a hunch, but I suspect there's nothing listening because even though the application hosting your service may still be running, the service host isn't.  In your constructor:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ControlChannel)))
    {
        host.Open();
    }
}
```

You have your `ServiceHost` in a `using` block - once the using block exits (right before the constructor finishes), the `ServiceHost` will be closed and disposed of.

Chang your code to this:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ControlChannel))
    host.Open();
}
```

You can hook into the application closing event to close the `ServiceHost` at the end of the program's run.

I'd also recommend wrapping the `host.Open()` in a try-catch block in case something goes wrong trying to open it.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I feel so stupid... Thanks. I set a Console.ReadLine() within the using, and now it works.